# When i run cv.imshow, I got error "QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread"

Tags: python, opencv, fedora

I use dnf install opencv.

```sh
sudo dnf install opencv opencv-contrib opencv-core opencv-devel opencv-doc python3-opencv
```

Then I run the python code:

```py
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('/home/a/dog.jpeg')
cv.imshow('dog', img)
```

Then I got the following error：

```py
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

My system is Fedora release 34.

Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about Wayland. Most probably your display server is Gnome with Wayland as the default. [**Solution 1**](https://geant4-forum.web.cern.ch/t/empty-see-through-graphics-window-in-qt-session-for-b1-example/2467):

> switched the session to Gnome with Xorg which uses X11 as the display server, the Qt GUI
> looks normal.

**Solution 2:**
I guess it is a common bug in fedora. I've found many similar issues with a quick search for different fedora versions ( 30, [31](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/646), 32 [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761280/qsocketnotifier-can-only-be-used-with-threads-started-with-qthread), 33). That's why, you can try to build `opencv` and set `WITH_QT` flag  OFF from the source rather than dnf package manager.

Not sure about the backbone of the problem but [the bug tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1967402) may help if RedHat cares.